# DB Exception while Dropping table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am somewhere wrong with syntax.

Crash comes when ever i call clearAll() method here is my method.

```
    /**
     * Method to clear all db
     */
    public void clearAll() {
        if(sqLiteDatabase==null){
            sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        }else {
            if(!sqLiteDatabase.isOpen()){
                sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        }
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_POSITIONS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_INDUSTRY);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_INTERESTS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_JOB_LOCATION);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_JOB_CITY);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_KNOWN_LANGUAGE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_ORGANIZATION_DETAILS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_QUALIFICATIONS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ SqlConstant.CREATE_TABLE_CURRENT_LOCATION);
    }
```

Query:

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS create table user_personal_detail ( first_name varchar2 , middle_name varchar2 , last_name varchar2 ,
>   user_name varchar2 , email_id varchar2 , alternative_email_id varchar2
>   , phone_number varchar2 , mobile_code varchar2 , date_of_birth
>   varchar2 , gender varchar2 , marrital_status varchar2 ,
>   education_level varchar2 , profile_image varchar2 , hupo_score
>   varchar2 , hupo_loyalty_point varchar2 , signup_date varchar2 ,
>   totalWorkExperience varchar2  )

Crash report:

> 04-02 16:11:50.943 23043-23043/com.app.hupo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       04-02 16:11:50.944 23043-23043/com.app.hupo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.app.hupo, PID: 23043
>                                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "create": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS create table
>   user_personal_detail ( first_name varchar2 , middle_name varchar2 ,
>   last_name varchar2 , user_name varchar2 , email_id varchar2 ,
>   alternative_email_id varchar2 , phone_number varchar2 , mobile_code
>   varchar2 , date_of_birth varchar2 , gender varchar2 , marrital_status
>   varchar2 , education_level varchar2 , profile_image varchar2 ,
>   hupo_score varchar2 , hupo_loyalty_point varchar2 , signup_date
>   varchar2 , totalWorkExperience varchar2  )
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
>                                                                         at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
>                                                                         at
>   com.app.hupo.database.DataBaseHelper.clearAll(DataBaseHelper.java:1048)
>                                                                         at

Comment: Update question with CREATE TABLE QUERY

Comment: You can uninstall and re-install app hope it will work or if this still occurs try to update DATABASE_VERSION

Comment: @Lucifer it is already available in crash report

Comment: @AkshayRohilla, I tried the same many times

Comment: Are there constraints between tables and tables have data ?

Comment: Where did you get that syntax:`DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE ...`?!

Comment: @RehanAzher, Nope

Comment: Could you show  the `SqlConstant` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "create": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS create table
>   user_personal_detail..

here, the *table name is missing* .

You need to remove **`SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+`**

Or use,

```
 SqlConstant.DROP_TABLE+ "tablename ;"+SqlConstant.CREATE_USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS)
```

Your command should be like,

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_personal_detail ; create table
>   user_personal_detail...

Do it for all the tables.

Comment: Then you need to use drop table if exists tablename. In your code table name is missing

Comment: Are you getting any exception after adding table name?

Comment: Same exception is coming

Comment: Please post the exception which you got now. And also do Clean your project,do invalidate caches then debug app